# breaking form fields up separately django

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a form that makes 14 fields, an opening and closing field for each day. I am having problems displaying each on its own, so I can include the days in between. My form is making fields such as 'open_time_1', 'close_time_1' up to 7. I currently have

`{{ schedule_form.fields.close_time_1 }}`

in my template, which was promising, but is causing 
[image]

How can I get the nitty gritty of django form fields in general to display manually like that? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try `{{ schedule_form.close_time_1 }}`.

This renders the field without any label markup. This is some code I use to render a field with bootstrap:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <span class="field-label">{{ field.label_tag }}</span>
    {% if field.field.required %}<span class="required">*</span>{% endif %}
    <span class="field-item">{{ field }}</span>
    <div class="field-help">{{ field.help_text }}</div>
    {% if field.errors %}<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">{{ field.errors }}</div>{% endif %}
</div>
```

Where field is eg. `schedule_form.close_time_1`.

More on the topic in [Django docs: Working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/).

Comment: that was very helpful, but I lose the normal form.as_p functionality- it doesn't display a name. do you know the way to display name as before? I get the select box but no formatting

Comment: it isn't letting me add a picture but before it was 

Open time: <box> and now is just <box>

Comment: `{{ schedule_form.close_time_1.label }}` will give you the label for the field I believe.

Comment: @codyc4321 updated answer, although I am not sure if I understand your second comment at all.

Comment: it isn't letting me add a picture to show you in the comments here. .label did work though, I started reading through the django.forms.baseform.as_p func and it was helpful, ty all

Comment: I am glad. You can always start a new question if what you wondr about is different, and paste the img in there.